# @WebFluxTest slice doesn't enable error handling

Tags: spring-boot

I'm testing my reactive rest api using @WebFluxTest and WebTestClient.

The controller under test has @Valid annotation in its body parameter

```
@PostMapping
public Mono<Route> add(@RequestBody @Valid Route route)
```

The Route class has this validation:

```
@NotBlank
private String code;
```

This is the test that sends code=null, and expects the error description to be present:

```
@Test
@WithMockUser
void add_shouldReturnError_givenARouteWithInvalidData() {

    Route route = new Route(null, "uri", 0, "name", List.of());

    client.mutateWith(csrf()).post().uri("/admin/api/routes")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(route))
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isBadRequest()
            .expectBody()
            .jsonPath("$.errors[0].field").isEqualTo("code")
            .jsonPath("$.errors[0].code").isEqualTo("NotBlank");
}
```

### The problem

The test it's failing because the response body is empty.
When testing the real app running, the response body contains the error description (matching the json paths included in the test).

I would expect that the @WebFluxTest test slice enabled the error handling for web flux, as is done in @WebMvcTest (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/reference/html/test-auto-configuration.html)

It is an expected behavior or a missing feature?

### Workaround

Adding this to my @WebFluxTest class corrects the behavior:

```
@ImportAutoConfiguration(ErrorWebFluxAutoConfiguration.class)
```

### Important data

- Spring Boot 2.1.3.RELEASE (tested also with 2.1.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT and 2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT)
- JUnit 5.3.2
- OpenJDK 11

Comment: Something similar has been fixed recently. Please take a look https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/16266